# How to secure/mask a file url with htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess

I have some pdfs that I want to post to my webserver.  I will then email a link for one or another to someone.  I want them to be able to download the pdf they got emailed a link to but  not be able to look in the folder that the file is hosted in... I also don't want to force the user to use a username/password... just want to mask the url to a pdf to keep prying eye's out of anything they weren't supposed to see.

The url would be something like

my_site.com/some_folder/some_file.pdf

But the user would see:

my_site.com/some_folder/somepage

Comment: that won't be very useful. It would be better to create some unguessable url. Something like `example.com/download/187bac6e9a/somefile.pdf`, where `187bac6e9a` would be different for every file. This way people can never guess the url of other files.

Comment: Thats not a bad idea.  Thanks very much!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you just want to stop directory listing? If so just use this:

```
Options -Indexes
```

Comment: I guess that covers most of this.  Does it make sense to mask the file url as well?